# С помощью ML для заданных целых чисел найти закономерности/свойства, которые их объединяют

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение

Вопрос - какая библиотека ML лучше подходит для задачи описанной ниже?

Задача

Для заданных чисел 3, 11, 23, 43, 83 (для примера взял простые целые числа) нужно выявить закономерности/свойства которые их объединяют, и в диапазоне от 1 до 100 найти другие целые числа, которые имею схожие свойства с точность N%.

В данном примере все числа нечетные и (n mod 4) = 3.

Конечной целью является написание функции, которая должна вернуть список "схожих" чисел с точностью N% для списка заданных чисел в диапазон чисел.

getListSimilarNumber(listSampleNumbers, startRange, endRange, accuracityPercent)

P.S. 
Цели решить задачу факторизации с помощью ML нет :)

Answer (score 2):

Никакой алгоритм ML не способен ответить на вопрос "выявить закономерности/свойства которые их объединяют". Алгоритмы ML в основном созданы для того, что-бы "предсказывать" значения неизвестных ранее объектов, предварительно обучившись по набору объектов, о которых "все" известно заранее.

Как можно это использовать в вашей задаче. Берете свою  последовательность  данных. Из нее удаляете несколько последних чисел.  Пропускаете через процесс обучения модели. Потом заставляете полученную модель "предсказать" несколько следующих чисел и сравниваете их с теми, что вы в начале удалили. Если эти последовательности более-менее совпадают (чем "более" тем лучше), значить модель "понимает" закономерность, лежащую в основе ваших данных.  Но точно она не опишет их словами или формулой, наподобие той, что вы привели.

Для применения этих алгоритмов на вход желательно подать как можно более длинную входную последовательность. Поэтому очень сомневаюсь, что на входной последовательности в 5 чисел вы получите что-либо вразумительное.  Кроме того,  поскольку мы по условию задачи не знаем, как-же в действительности генерируется ваша последовательность, сказать, какого именно класса модели ряда мы ищем, предсказать какой алгоритм заранее также не получиться.

В общем, при указанных вводных, врят-ли какая из готовых функций вам поможет. Но на вопрос "в каких библиотеках функции такого класса собраны" - точка начала поиска - библиотека  scikit-learn.  Если ваши последовательности все-таки  очччччееееенььь длинные :-), можете посмотреть TensorFlow, хотя в успех я не верею.